# How WE can make this type of code responsive in Landscape Mode for flutter as this gives error at Column

Tags: flutter, responsive

**Need Help for responsive  design in Flutter**

> Gives renderflex error for colunm
> but the main cause is Sliver
> *Need Help in learning responsive design*
> This code is taken from Flutter with Gia developer youTube

```
Scaffold(
   body: CustomScrollView(
     slivers: [
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
          SizedBox(
            width: Get.width,
            height: Get.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Spacer(flex: 6),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: _HeaderText(),
                ),
                Spacer(flex: 4),
                _IllustrationImage(),
                Spacer(flex: 4),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: _PhoneNumberField(),
                ),
                Spacer(flex: 2),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: _LoginButton(),
                ),
                Spacer(flex: 5),
                _RegistrationButton(),
                Spacer(flex: 2),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
       ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using OrientationBuilder you can update the UI based on Orientation.

```dart
body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          return CustomScrollView(
            scrollDirection: orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? Axis.vertical
                : Axis.horizontal,
          );
        },
      ),
```

For more info go here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation

Comment: not working as it gives bottom overflow try giving another solution <init state have a dialog which also cause error if i use orientation builder>